# Word problem about elevator capacity of children vs adults.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The capacity of an elevator is either 15 children or 11 adults?  If 9 children are currently on the elevator how many adults can still get in?

Comment: Missing information.  Please provide all necessary information to solving the problem and we can help you, and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: It depends on the weight of each person in the elevator, of course. I'm joking, but there is something very strange. Maybe the answer is "the integer part of the number $x$ such that $15/11=9/x$"?

Comment: that is all the info I am given. Also would you kindly remove your dwonvote.

Comment: If 9 children are already in the elevator, I would wait for the next one.

Comment: I think the assumption that all children weigh one amount and all adults weigh some other amount (made by both responders) is a reasonable one, given the problem statement.  Given that, it is soluble.

Comment: I misread the question then.  I assumed he was trying to solve for the capacity of the elevator.

Comment: @Neil Downvoting for "missing info" isn't fair to the OP if - as likely - the problem was posed this way. It is not uncommon that elementary word problems are posed poorly.

Comment: This question doesn't need downvotes, it needs editing.  I will give it a try.

Comment: In addition to editing the problem might benefit from a modicum of effort by the OP?

Comment: At first, I downvoted because *this question sucks!* But after a minute or two, I un-downvoted because the OP doesn't have any control over that. But now I'm thinking about downvoting again, as he hasn't shown any effort.

Answer (score 11):

Assume that each child weighs $1$ unit, whence the capacity of the elevator is $15$ units. This makes the weight of each adult $\frac{15}{11}\approx 1.36$ units.

If the elevator is occupied by $9$ children, i.e. $9$ units, you're left with $6$ units. How many adults would fit into those units?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that  children have equal weights , and  adults have equal weights also . Let's denote weight of children as $x$ , weight of adults as : $y$ , and capacity of the elevator as $C$  , then:

$C=15x=11y \Rightarrow x=\frac{11}{15}y$

$C \geq9x+ny \Rightarrow 6x \geq ny$

$6\cdot \frac{11}{15} y \geq ny \Rightarrow n=\left \lfloor \frac{66}{15} \right \rfloor =4 $

Comment: Very helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**  wlog, by *scaling*, max weight = $15\!\cdot\! 11,\:$ with weights: $\:\!$ child $= 11,\:$ adult $= 15.$

With $9\:\!$ children, remaining weight $ = 15\!\cdot\! 11-9\!\cdot\! 11 = 6\!\cdot\! 11,\:$ enough for $66/15 = 22/5$ adults.

Note how the arithmetic simplifies by exploiting an innate *scaling symmetry*. This allows us to choose any convenient unit of weight measurement. Thus we can assume that the unit of weight is chosen so that the elevator weight capacity is divisible by both $15$ and $11,\:$ for example $15\!\cdot\!11.\:$ Doing so helps, for as long as possible, to keep the arithmetic computations simple (involving only integers vs. fractions). For some less trivial examples of solving word problems by way of exploiting innate symmetries see V. Arnold's famous [sunrise problem.](http://groups.google.com/groups/search?q=group%3A%2amath%2a+author%3Adubuque+sunrise)